# CheckBox as datatemplate in a ListBox reset IsChecked value when scrolling

Tags: wpf, binding, checkbox, listbox, datatemplate

I want to start using MVVM in my project so I have started to investigate it.
While I was playing a bit with WPF I've encountered a bug that I couldn't find a solution to him by myself and while exploring internet.

I have something like that(I can't paste my full code because its not in the same network):

MainView.Xaml

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
        <my:AddToInvitation />
     </i:EventTrigger>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
        <my:RemoveFromInvitation />
     </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   </CheckBox>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> Persons { get; set; }

public MainViewModel()
{
  this.Persons = new ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>();
  for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
  {
     PersonViewModel personVM = new PersonViewModel (string.Format("Person - {0}",i));
     this.Persons.add(personVM);
  }
}
```

PersonViewModel.cs

```
private Person PersonObject { get; set; }

public string Name
{
  get
  {
     return this.PersonObject.Name;
  }
}

public PersonViewModel(string personName)
{
  this.PersonObject = new Person(personName);
}
```

Person.cs

```
public string Name { get; set; }

public Person(string name)
{
   this.Name = name;
}
```

Now if you try to paste it and run it, it will look just fine.
The problem is when you try the following instructions:

```
1) Check the first 10 persons in the ListBox.
2) Scroll down the ListBox to the bottom of it.
3) Leave the mouse when the list box is scrolled down.
4) Scroll back up to the top of the ListBox.
5) Poof! you'r checking disappeared.
```

Now the solution i have found to this is to add IsChecked property(Though I don't really need it) to the PersonViewModel and bind it to the CheckBox IsChecked DependencyProperty, but then I have added a functionality that lets the user to press a button and it will iterate over all the persons in the ListBox and change it IsChecked property to true(Button -> Select all).
Following to the disappear Checks bug I have crossed another bug which I believe somehow is connected to the disappearing Checks - the actions that I have put to trigger when Check and Uncheck occurs would trigger only for some of the CheckBoxes when you select all.
I tried to count how many times the actions would happen when I used the select all function and I found a connection between the height of the ListBox(Current Visible CheckBoxes) and the amount of the triggers that fired, furthermore I scrolled to the middle of the ListBox and used the SelectAll functionality and the triggers didn't fire until the loop encountered the first visible ChekBox that I can see in my ListBox.

Its a bit hard to understand this bug if you don't try it, so please comment here only if you tried this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: You are going against the current.

The binding is all about changing value in your ViewModel and allowing you to write your code against simple view model classes so that your presentation logic is free of business logic. In your example the decision to execute  `AddToInvitation` `RemoveFromInvitation` is in your view and it should not be there.

You will be good with `bool IsInvited{get;set;}` property that is easily bound to checkbox (no dependency property required). And this will allow user changes to be persisted in your view model.  If you need some other more complicated logic you should attach to `PropertyChagned` event form `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface that your ViewModel must implement. Then you can change property in your simple class at will and ui will update accordingly.

Comment: The triggers AddToInvitation and RemoveFromInvitation are just an example, I am trying to simply activate a trigger and not register to the event. As I recall WPF should let me do it but I can't do it, therefore I think it will be more wise to open a call in microsoft service for a bug then just let go and start making workarounds.